# What is the equivalent terminal command to findsmb on Lion

Tags: macos, terminal

The [findsmb](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/10.6/man1/findsmb.1.html) command present in SnowLeopard and older, is not available from terminal in Lion. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks like you should be able to re install it yourself manually.

1. Install [samba3](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/samba3/Portfile) using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)
2. Put the contents of [the source for findsmb perl script](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/samba/samba-23/packaging/RedHat/findsmb) into a file named findsmb, make it executable in using [chmod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chmod.2.html) and then add it your path to regain the findsmb program.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `smbutil lookup` to resolve IP to NetBIOS names